# Get a tree of files in a bare git repo on at a specific commit

Tags: git, git-bare

You can use `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` on a bare repo to get all the files in that repo, but I want that list for specific commits.

I.e. I want to walk though a repo commit by commit from the first commit until I'm at HEAD and see how the file tree has evolved.  I only care about the files and paths, I don't actually care about the contents.

Is there a way to do this on a bare repo?  I want this on a bare repo because we have some very large repos and doing a checkout for each commit would be far too costly in CPU time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just replace `HEAD` with any commit-or-tree identifier, such as an SHA-1 or any of the specifiers allowed by [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

To get SHA-1 IDs, use [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).  For instance, to work from the current commit (`HEAD`) back to the root following only first parents at each merge:

```
git rev-list --first-parent --topo-order HEAD | while read rev; do
    git ls-tree --full-tree -r $rev
done
```

To run through the same set of revisions in the other order, add `--reverse` to the arguments to `git rev-list`.

If you want to follow all parents at merges, you can simply omit `--first-parent`.  The `--topo-order` restriction will ensure that parent commit IDs come before (or with `--reverse`, after) all their children.  Without a specific sort, you get the commits in reverse (or with `--reverse`, forward) order by commit-date.

(If you're going to track the tree as it evolves but also want to handle merges nicely, you may need a more complex operation here, where you have `git rev-list` produce the parent and child commit IDs together, since even with `--topo-order` or some other sorting criterion keeping parent/child relationships together, it's not going to be obvious, from a flattened graph, exactly where the merge happened.  Read [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) thoroughly for this.  Using `--first-parent` simplifies the job enormously since it gives you a simplified, strict parent/child ordering.)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I thought that was what I was trying and it wasn't working. Well, it works now. Thanks.